# How to change background of Dashboard in Lion

Tags: macos, graphics, dashboard

I find the default background of Dashboard in Lion quite boring.  I know how to change the defaultdesktop.jpg for the login screen, and I was wondering if there was a similar process for Dashboard.  Thanks.

Current Background "Texture:"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding file seems to be located at

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/pirelli.png
```

It's a little piece of the pattern that's tiled: [image]

You can try replacing this with another tile of the same size, or even a larger image and see if it works! Then relaunch the Dock (from Activity Monitor or `killall Dock`) and it should show up.